# Access the value of text field from another class

Tags: ios, ios5

I am making an app using a utility application template. I am trying to access the value of a UITextField from the FlipSideVewController class.

In the MainViewController.h file I have -

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>{

UITextField *textField;
NSString *myText;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myText;
-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender;
```

In the MainViewController.m file -

```
myText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: textField.text];
NSLog(@"%@",myText);
```

I am creating the FlipSideViewController in the MainViewController class using the following code -

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

This prints the value of the textfield in the console without any problems. The problem happens when I try to access the value of the textfield in the FlipSideVewController class (after the user presses the go button).

In the FlipViewController class I have -

```
MainViewController *obj = [[MainViewController alloc] init ];
NSString *abc = obj.textField.text;  
NSLog(@"%@",abc);
```

The FlipSideVewController nib file is loaded fine without any problems. However the console output is **(null)** when in FlipSideVewController.

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to your MainViewController and declare your textField as a property first and synthesize it, so you can access it using obj.textField. And if you have just created obj using alloc and init, you wont have any text in the textField instance Variable.

MainViewController.h

```
@property (retain) UITextField *textField;
```

MainViewController.m

```
@synthesize textField;
```

and you could use

```
myText=textField.text;
```

Now this should do it and you can access this textField by obj.textField in your other class. But you still wont get its value if you are initializing it in your other class because you will be creating a brand new obj whose textField.text will be blank( unless you have overrided its designated initializer to set the textField.text value).

Declare NSString *abc as instance variable

```
NSString *abc;
```

and then as property

```
@property (copy) NSString *abc;
@synthesize abc;
```

After you create your FlipSideViewController,

```
controller.abc=myText;
```

Remove the code where you create obj.
This will do it.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question so that it includes the code from the MainViewController.h file and MainViewController.m file. Basically, I want the user to type in something in a text field and when he enters the Go button, he will go to the next view. In the second view I want to use the string the user entered previously. Thanks

Comment: look at the edited answer. But I still need you to tell me how you are traversing through the objects.

Comment: ok, I saw your edited question. You are creating a new instance of your MainViewController. Please show the code where you create your FlipSideViewController.

Comment: Edited the question and it now includes the code to generate the FlipSideViewController.

Comment: I am able to access the text field, but in the console, the value printed is (null), so I guess the textField.text is blank. How do I overcome that problem ?

Comment: ok, look at the updated answer and it should solve your issue.

Comment: I get an error saying "Property 'abc' not found on object of type 'FlipSideViewController'

Comment: you did not create the nsstring as instance variable(now shown in my edit). And remove the 2 lines where you create obj and assign abc

Comment: Figured out the mistake. I declared the string "abc" in MainViewController instead of FlipSide... Thanks a lot for the help :D

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Utility Xcode template, you should think of `MainViewController` and `FlipSideVewController` as given: the framework will instantiate them for you and make it available to the rest of the program as you define (either in your code or in IB). What I mean by this is that your line:

```
MainViewController *obj = [[MainViewController alloc] init ];
```

does not really do what you want.

In your case, what you seems to want is access a text field controlled by the existing `MainViewController` instance (the one that gives you the `NSLog` output correctly) from your other existing `FlipSideVewController` instance. This is a matter of "connectin" somehow those two controllers.

There are several ways to accomplish this. One is defining a "model" for your app and have it shared between the controllers. See also the [Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html) pattern. A model is just a data structure that contains your "data"; you make that data structure available to both of your controllers. The easiest way to create such data structure and have it shared is through a singleton (I am not suggesting to use it as the best way, just noting that it is the *easiest* way, IMO).

Another, less clean way is passing a reference to `MainViewController` to `FlipSideVewController` and then accessing the text field through it. By example, you could define an ivar in your `FlipSideVewController`, then, where the two controllers are created, you do the assignment to the ivar.